# Keep table headers on screen as user scrolls

Tags: hover, html-table, scrollbar

I have an HTML page that contains a table.  The table headers get eventually scrolled off the top of the screen, but I would like the headers to stay visible at the top.

I want to use a method like alaskaair.com's "Fares Selected" widget. Their little Fares widget stays visible as you scroll the page: [Screenshot of alaskaair.com widget](http://img166.imageshack.us/img166/6699/alaskaairexample.png).

Note that in my case it would look more like this: [Simple Mockup](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/3597/simplemockup.png)

Comment: The images links are now dead making the question unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation recently (creating an inbox-style display for notifications), and after some googling, I came across these:

1. http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html
2. http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bulletVersion.html

I'm presently using (1) and I haven't encountered any issues with it so far. You can follow the discussion of the solution [here](http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/46422).

**EDIT**
I just re-read your question, and I guess this isn't exactly what you were looking for. Still, maybe it'll be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I use xTableHeaderFixed to freeze my headers:

http://cross-browser.com/x/lib/view.php?s=xTableHeaderFixed

Comment: This is exactly what I need! I also found this: http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/fixed_menu.html
But you link is better!